# Given a closed subspace $K$, is there always a linear functional whose kernel is $K$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a closed subspace $K$, is there always a linear functional whose kernel is $K$?

I could not think of any way to show that this is true, so I think this must be false. However, I have no clue how to prove that.

Comment: The kernel of a *functional* must have codimension at most $1$, therefore the answer is "No".

Comment: @Gae.S. Does that follow form Rank nullity theorem for infinite dimensions? For example if $K$ is finite dimensional then there is not linear functional that has it as a kernel if the whole space is infinite dimensional?

Comment: It follows from the first isomorphism theorem: there is exactly one linear function $g: V/\ker\phi\to \operatorname{im}\phi$ such that $\phi=g\circ \pi_{\ker\phi}$, and said function is bijective. Therefore $1\ge\dim\operatorname{im}\phi=\dim (V/\ker\phi)$. This is a purely algebraic fact which holds regardless of the topological structure.

Comment: Gae is right of course, but I think you can see this from scratch, more intuitively, without the first isomorphism theorem. As in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $f\in L(X,\mathbb F)$ and  $y\notin \text{ker}\ f,$ let $x\in X$. Then $x=\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}y+\left(x-\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}y\right)$, which shows that $X=\text{span}\ y\oplus \text{ker}\ f.$ Now note that $\dim\ \text{span}\ y=1.$